# SQL exclusion regexp does not work, why?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have some sentences in db. I want to select the ones that don't have urls in them.

So what I do is

```
select ID, SENTENCE
from SENTENCE_TABLE
where regexp_like(SENTENCE, '[^http]');
```

However after the query is executed the sentences that appear in the results pane still have urls. I tried a lot of other combinations without any success. 
Can somebody explain or give a *good* link where it is explained how regexps actually work in SQL.

**How can I filter(exclude) actual words in db with SQL query?**

Comment: Why do you think that SQL has its own interpretation? This regexp won't work as you expect in any language.

Comment: @minerals, first off it's considered rude to "update" your question. If you have a new question please ask one. Secondly "does not work" is not an error message. I have already answered your first and second question so I'm unsure what else you want. a CASE does not _exclude_, it provides a pseudo column.

Comment: I am really sorry @Ben, I was not attentive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're over-complicating this. Just use a standard [LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52142).

```
select ID, SENTENCE
  from SENTENCE_TABLE
  where SENTENCE not like '%http%';
```

`regexp_like(SENTENCE, '[^http]')` will match everything *but* h, t and p separately. I like the [PSOUG page](http://psoug.org/snippet/Regular-Expressions--REGEXP_REPLACE_882.htm) on regular expressions in Oracle but I would also recommend reading [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501).

To respond to your comment you *can* use REGEXP_LIKE, there's just no point.

```
select ID, SENTENCE
  from SENTENCE_TABLE
 where not regexp_like(SENTENCE, 'http');
```

This looks for the string `http` rather than the letters individually.

Comment: oh, it is "not" that excludes it, finally) Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`[^http]` would match any character except `h` **or** `t` **or** `t` **or** `p`..So this would match any string that doesn't contain `h` **or** `t` **or** `t` **or** `p` anywhere in the string

It should be `where not regexp_like(SENTENCE, '^http');`..this would match anything that doesn`t start with http

Comment: This won't work in Oracle. It doesn't support the full POSIX or Perl standards.